# JS errors on cartoDB map editor - tracker.js

Tags: carto, map-editor

When editing my map in the CartoDB interface the page breaks with errors - see screenshot.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

tracker.js:14cartodb/table/views/tooltip/custom_templates/infowindow_light not found

infowindow_html_pane.js:202Uncaught TypeError: cdb.templates.getTemplate(...) is not a function(…)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of error I would recommend contacting CARTO support